# Move the rectangle with the mouse

Tags: c#, winforms, selection, move

I wrote this code:

```
private struct MovePoint
    {
        public int X;
        public int Y;
    }
private void Image_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        FirstPoint = new MovePoint();
        FirstPoint.X = e.X;
        FirstPoint.Y = e.Y;
    }

    private void Image_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if(e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
        {
            if(FirstPoint.X > e.X)
            {
                Rectangle.X = FirstPoint.X - e.X;
                //Rectangle.Width -= FirstPoint.X - e.X;
            } else
            {
                Rectangle.X = FirstPoint.X + e.X;
                //Rectangle.Width += FirstPoint.X + e.X;
            }

            if(FirstPoint.Y > e.Y)
            {
                Rectangle.Y = FirstPoint.Y - e.Y;
                //Rectangle.Height -= FirstPoint.Y - e.Y;
            } else
            {
                Rectangle.Y = FirstPoint.Y + e.Y;
                //Rectangle.Height += FirstPoint.Y + e.Y;
            }

            Image.Invalidate();
        }
    }
private void Image_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        if(Pen != null) e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(Pen, Rectangle);
    }
```

Rectangle moves, but with inversion (it should not be). Can you help?

Comment: You never give the rectangle a Width or Height.

Comment: @Hans: This looks to only be a snippet. If the rectangle did not have an initial width and height, the OP could not have seen it moving (albeit incorrectly). :)

Comment: @HansPassant: Width and Height given, but I have not posted this piece of code

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The mathematics in your mouse-move handler for moving the rectangle based on the mouse-movements seems quite off; I think you want something like this:

```
private void Image_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
    {
        int initialX = 0, initialY = 0; // for example.

        Rectangle.X = (e.X - FirstPoint.X) + initialX; 
        Rectangle.Y = (e.Y - FirstPoint.Y) + initialY;

        Image.Invalidate();
    }
}
```

This way, the rectangle's upper left corner will follow the mouse by tracking the delta between the *initial* mouse-down location and the *current* mouse location. Note however that each time you re-click and drag, the rectangle will move back to its *original* location.

If, instead,  you want the Rectangle to 'remember' its position across multiple click-and-drag operations (i.e. not to be reinitialized to its initial location on mouse-down) you can do:

```
private void Image_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
    {
        // Increment rectangle-location by mouse-location delta.
        Rectangle.X += e.X - FirstPoint.X; 
        Rectangle.Y += e.Y - FirstPoint.Y; 

        // Re-calibrate on each move operation.
        FirstPoint = new MovePoint { X = e.X, Y = e.Y };

        Image.Invalidate();
    }
}
```

One other suggestion: There's no need to create your own `MovePoint` type when there's already the `System.Drawing.Point` type. Also, in general, try not to create mutable structs.

Comment: Thank you very much! Especially in the second part of the answer (thought how to fix this bug with reset position).